# Why does istream::get set cin.fail when '\n' is the first character?

Tags: c++, stream

Why these two functions istream::get(char*, streamsize) and istream::get(char*, streamsize, char) set the cin.fail bit when they find '\n' as the first character in the cin buffer?

As can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165167/istream-and-cin-get/12166297#12166297), that's the behavior of the two overloads mentioned above. I'd like to know what was the purpose in designing these functions this way ? Note that both functions leave the character '\n' in the buffer, but if you call any of them a second time, they will fail because of the newline character, as shown in the link. Wouldn't it make more sense to make these two functions not to leave the character '\n' in the buffer, as the overloads of the function istream::get() and istream::getline() do ?

Comment: Why `get` is not identical to `getline`, you ask? What would the point be?

Comment: You're right. By discarding '\n', get(char*, streamsize) would be equal to getline(). But again, what is the point of having a function like get() that leaves '\n' in the buffer and fails when called a second time?

Comment: The second version allows you to specify the delimiter, which can then be something other than `'\n'`. It is *you* who decide if you want to use the same delimiter twice (bad idea), not the library.

Answer (score 1):

With [`std::istream::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/), if the delimiting character is found it is extracted and discarded. With [`std::istream::get`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) the delimiting character remains in the stream.

With `getline` you don't know, if the delimiting character was read and discarded or if just `n - 1` characters where read. If you only want to read whole lines, you can use `get` and then `peek` for the next character and see if it is a newline or the given delimiter.

But if you want to read whole lines up to some delimiter, you might also use [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/), which reads the complete line in any case.

Comment: I guess the reasoning  is that if `get` doesn't get anything at all, that is considered a failure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My question however is more about the reason for the existence of this function. I'd like to know of one case where get(char*, streamsize) would be more useful than getline(char*, streamsize) ?

Comment: You might want to use `get(buffer, 5)` to get the first part of a line that you know is much longer than that.

Comment: @BoPersson getline(buffer,5) would give you the same result

Comment: Yes, but that might also confuse people expecting `getline` to read the full line.

Comment: @BoPersson For me at least it's been much more confusing to understand the reason why these two get() overloads exist at all.

Comment: @user1577873 Then your question title is a bit misleading. Anyway, sorry for the noise.