# "cin.get" stopped another input function like "cin" .. c++

Tags: c++

I want to request the a username and password from 6 users,
and then save this username and password into a text file on my desktop.
I built a structure that has one variable to store the password and a `char` array with a length of 25.

```
struct users {
    int password;
    char username[25];
}
```

When I want to request the username in the `main()` function, I use  the `cin.get()` function.

```
cin.get(username,25);
```

The program stops after the second `cin` function when it is storing the password. Why is that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 

struct users {
    char username[25];
    int password;
} user[6]; 

using namespace std;
int main() {  
    cout << "Sign up x6" << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        cout << "Username:";
        cin.get(user[i].username,20);
        cout << "Password:";
        cin >> user[i].password;
    }
    std::ofstream file;
    file.open("C:/Users/Programmer/Desktop/sa.txt",ios::app);
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        file << "first user\n" << user[i].username << endl << user[i].password << endl;
        cout << "\n \n \n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Not strictly a duplicate, but Dietmar Kühl's answer explains the problem and offers solutions: [istream and cin.get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165167/istream-and-cin-get)

Comment: i found solution..

Comment: @YasserA.ElShbrawy Could you please answer your own question with the solution you found? It will help people with the same problem in the future.

Comment: @SeanDawson Done.  <br>
thank you for your help ..

Answer (score -1):

i found solution that using **"gets"** function .. which inside **stdio.h** library: 
function **"gets"** will request the user of value then store the value of  variable. **(username)** 
char username[25]; 
gets(username[25]);

but this function **"gets"** get only value of **"char"** type **variables** so i changed **"password"** variable type to **char** 
char password[25]; 
gets(password[25]);

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include <fstream> 
    #include<stdio.h>
struct users
{
char username[25];
char password[25];
} user[6];
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout << "Sign up x6" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    cout << "username:";
    gets(user[i].username);
    cout << "Password:";
    gets(user[i].password);
}
std::ofstream file;
file.open("C:/Users/Programmer/Desktop/sa.txt", ios::app);
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    file <<"("<<i<<") user\n" << user[i].username << endl <<  user[i].password<< endl;          
    cout << "\n \n \n";
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

use std::cin.getline(user[i].username,20) instead.

Comment: Suffers almost exactly the same problem as the asker's code. The '\n' most likely left in the stream after `cin >> user[i].password;` breaks the parser.

Comment: after i did that ,, the cin.getline function run only once inside "for loop"
so asked me of password 6 times (true)
but asked me of username only once time! (false)